# Paypal adaptive payments no longer accepting new applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

After a lot of digging we have paypal adaptive payments working in the sandbox with embedded/chained payments using the [paypal_adaptive gem](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive). Now the time has come to try out the live payment system, and as far as I can tell it seems that paypal is no longer giving out the X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID needed to use the service (?).

The submission process described in [this thread](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/require-my-x-paypal-application-id) no longer seems to exist, and eventually I noticed this message in the sidebar :

> The application submission form and application management tools (MyApps) for PayPal apps are currently offline so that we can launch a new and improved tool.
>   If you have questions about your app that has already been submitted, please select the "What's Up with My App?" option on our contact form.
>   We appreciate your patience while we work to improve x.com.

We've invested a reasonable amount of time getting everything working via the sandbox, and there was no indication during this time that the live service was unusable, though in hindsight we should have picked this up sooner. Nor can I find any information as to when this happened, and how long it's expected to be offline for.

I have sent a mail via the support system but am yet to hear back - does anyone have any idea what's going on with the adaptive payments service or when it might be available again, or if there's any other way to apply for an X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It came back up last night.

Despite repeated attempts by me and other members of paypal's dev community, we didn't get a concrete date until it was back up (I only noticed because I check every morning).

You can fill in an application here: https://www.x.com/user/my-account/applications/new

Depending on how advanced your integration is, they will generally give you a live AppID and approve the app automatically, then a human will review your app in the next 2 days or so - although I would suppose that there is a bit of an avalanche of app submissions going on at the moment so they might take a bit longer.

as an aside: strangely enough it was me that posted the original question that @recurser linked to, I guess this explains the 500 views :)

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging, it appears that it is scheduled to return [November 7th~8th](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/anyone-know-when-app-submission-will-be-back-online).

Answer (score 0):

Its already Nov 15 and it still is offline, after spending almost 2 days on this i havent found any response from paypal people.

Comment: It's open for applications again now - the app was 'conditionally approved' straight away and they provided a live X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID.

Comment: we've had a website held up for almost a month now, consider yourself lucky you only had to wait 2 days :) also, if you want a response for dev help, ask it here: http://dts.custhelp.com/app/ask instead of on x.com as they don't seem to answer support requests at all, however I got a response in 10 minutes from the dts site.